# How to prove this theorem using order axioms?

Tags: proof-writing, order-theory

I need to prove that if $\space\space0<a<b\space$ then $\space0<b^{-1}<a^{-1}$.

Comment: What 'order axioms' are you referring to?

Comment: you mean order axioms of an ordered field like $\Bbb R$? Just Remember the axiom that says if $x\le y$ then $z\cdot x\le z\cdot y$ for $z\ge 0$.

Comment: The order axioms for the Real numbers, the ones involving trichotomy, and inequalites

Comment: Do you refer to real numbers? I mean do you want to take ordered field?

Comment: Use the homomorphism $x \to e^{x}$, then it remains to show what is abvious and come back. (for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ab\gt0$, so:

$$\frac{a}{ab}\lt\frac{b}{ab}$$

$$\frac{1}{b}\lt\frac{1}{a}$$